# jquery popups - have multiple links but need only one popup that stays in the foreground

Tags: jquery, popup

I have multiple links to the same jquery popup in my html page.  The actual form inside the popup will be different depending on which link brought that popup up.  But the actual popup itself will be the same.  The page content is dynamic, and I never know where the link to the popup will show up and which form it will contain.

I am having 3 problems with implementation:

1. The buttons (images) that I use as a links to click and bring up the popup show through the popup and the text it contains.  I've tried setting the z attribute in css in various places and to various values, with no effect.
2. The button link stays in the foreground and is clickable, while the form inside the popup is disabled.
3. If I click on another button link, I get a second popup.  I'd like the first popup to close before the second one is brought up.

You can see the problems in example in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/azxf4/2/

popup.css

```
.popbox {
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}


.collapse { position:relative; }

 .box {
  display:block;
  display:none;
  background:#FFF;
  border:solid 1px #BBBBBB;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #999;
  position:absolute;
}
.open {}

  .box a.close {
   color:red;
   font-size:12px;
   font-family:arial;
   text-decoration:underline;
  }

  .arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #FFF;
    position:absolute;
    left:1px;
    top:-10px;
    z-index:1001;
  }

  .arrow-border {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #BBBBBB;
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    z-index:1000;
  }
```

popup.js

```
(function(){

$.fn.popbox = function(options){
var settings = $.extend({
  selector      : this.selector,
  open          : '.open',
  box           : '.box',
  arrow         : '.arrow',
  arrow_border  : '.arrow-border',
  close         : '.close'
}, options);
var methods = {
  open: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pop = $(this);
    var box = $(this).parent().find(settings['box']);

    box.find(settings['arrow']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});
    box.find(settings['arrow_border']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});

    if(box.css('display') == 'block'){
      methods.close();
    } else {
      box.css({'display': 'block', 'top': 10, 'left': ((pop.parent().width()/2) -box.width()/2 )});
    }
  },

  close: function(){
    $(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");
  }
};

$(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 27){
    methods.close();
  }
});

$(document).bind('click', function(event){
  if(!$(event.target).closest(settings['selector']).length){
    methods.close();
  }
});

return this.each(function(){
  $(this).css({'width': $(settings['box']).width()}); // Width needs to be set otherwise popbox will not move when window resized.
  $(settings['open'], this).bind('click', methods.open);
  $(settings['open'], this).parent().find(settings['close']).bind('click', methods.close);
});
}

}).call(this);
```

html

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <div class='popbox'><a class='open' href='#'><img src='http://thezoovninc.com/images/Web/New%20folder/plusButton.png' width='30' height='30'></a>

        <div class='collapse'>
            <div class='box'>
                <div class='arrow'></div>
                <div class='arrow-border'></div>
                <form action='someActionPage.jsp' id='actionId'>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <div class='input'>Last Name:<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /> </div>
                    <div class='input'>First Name:<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /> </div>
                    <div class='close'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Add' /> <a href='#'>Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>


    <div class='popbox'><a class='open' href='#'><img src='http://thezoovninc.com/images/Web/New%20folder/plusButton.png' width='30' height='30'></a>

        <div class='collapse'>
            <div class='box'>
                <div class='arrow'></div>
                <div class='arrow-border'></div>
                <form action='someActionPage.jsp' id='actionId'>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <div class='input'>Last Name:<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /> </div>
                    <div class='input'>First Name:<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /> </div>
                    <div class='close'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Add' /> <a href='#'>Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
 <div class='popbox'><a class='open' href='#'><img src='http://thezoovninc.com/images/Web/New%20folder/plusButton.png' width='30' height='30'></a>

        <div class='collapse'>
            <div class='box'>
                <div class='arrow'></div>
                <div class='arrow-border'></div>
                <form action='someActionPage.jsp' id='actionId'>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <div class='input'>Last Name:<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /> </div>
                    <div class='input'>First Name:<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /> </div>
                    <div class='close'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Add' /> <a href='#'>Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   <div class='popbox'><a class='open' href='#'><img src='http://thezoovninc.com/images/Web/New%20folder/plusButton.png' width='30' height='30'></a>

        <div class='collapse'>
            <div class='box'>
                <div class='arrow'></div>
                <div class='arrow-border'></div>
                <form action='someActionPage.jsp' id='actionId'>
                    <p>test</p>
                    <div class='input'>Last Name:<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname' /> </div>
                    <div class='input'>First Name:<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' /> </div>
                    <div class='close'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Add' /> <a href='#'>Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" >
         $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".popbox").popbox();
    });
      </script>
      </body>
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.  Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with this same jQuery plugin.

While I'm not an expert programmer, I seem to have resolved the problem by adding this line

$(".box").css({"display": "none"});

in the open function:

```
      open: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var pop = $(this);
    var box = $(this).parent().find(settings['box']);

     $(".box").css({"display": "none"});

    box.find(settings['arrow']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});
    box.find(settings['arrow_border']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});

    if(box.css('display') == 'block'){
      methods.close();
    } else {
      box.css({'display': 'block', 'top': 10, 'left': ((pop.parent().width()/2) -box.width()/2 )});
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

To close all the pop-ups try following:
a. Add "close" event listener
b. Call close before opening other pop-up boxes

```
(function(){

$.fn.popbox = function(options){
var settings = $.extend({
  selector      : this.selector,
  open          : '.open',
  box           : '.box',
  arrow         : '.arrow',
  arrow_border  : '.arrow-border',
  close         : '.close'
}, options);
var methods = {
  open: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pop = $(this);
    var box = $(this).parent().find(settings['box']);

    $(settings['open']).trigger("close"); // trigger a close event for all 

    box.find(settings['arrow']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});
    box.find(settings['arrow_border']).css({'left': box.width()/2 - 10});

    if(box.css('display') == 'block'){
      methods.close();
    } else {
      box.css({'display': 'block', 'top': 10, 'left': ((pop.parent().width()/2) -box.width()/2 )});
    }
  },

  close: function(){
    $(settings['box']).fadeOut("fast");
  }
};

$(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 27){
    methods.close();
  }
});

$(document).bind('click', function(event){
  if(!$(event.target).closest(settings['selector']).length){
    methods.close();
  }
});

return this.each(function(){
  $(this).css({'width': $(settings['box']).width()}); // Width needs to be set otherwise popbox will not move when window resized.
  $(settings['open'], this).bind('click', methods.open);
  $(settings['open'], this).parent().find(settings['close']).bind('click', methods.close);
  $(this).bind('close', methods.close); // have a close event
});
}

}).call(this);
```

-- And this is a CSS fix for #1 (Tried IE8 and FF18)

```
.box {
  display:block;
  display:none;
  background:#FFF;
  border:solid 1px #BBBBBB;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #999;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike.  Z-index set to 1000 works!  But I'm still getting multiple popups, the close event doesn't seem to be doing anything...